# Getting an error trying to submit app to showcase

Tags: uses-of-open-data

When I try and submit my app to the showcase at:

https://datasf.org/showcase/made-with-open-data-survey/

I get a error: "Error saving"

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Please contact the respective website operators. Knowing nothing about your showcase, the amount of data, which exact steps you undertook, etc. the stackexchange community will not be able to help you. Please either elaborate so that we are able to follow you step by step or delete the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.